# Need to get absolute path of a webpage using Java

Tags: java, http, download, kotlin, absolute-path

I am writing a program that downloads some HTML. I need to retain the original filenames and folder structure as are on the server, so I need a way to handle links like "www.google.com". If you type it in, it will obviously download some PHP, but I need to know exactly what that file is called. I am writing in Kotlin, but if you can provide an answer in Java that'll work.

Comment: `URL.getPath` should provide you with that information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to retain the original filenames and folder structure as are on the server

This not possible, you cannot know the structure of the data on the server.  There may not even exist a file and folder structure on the server, the returned data could be all dynamically generated an not be based on a filesystem.